# Find and Find Next

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using two forms, where one is a rich text editor with menus and a rich text box and the second form is for search and replace and contains four button and two text boxes. I have managed to do the find button but I am having problems with Find Next. I am using C# Windows Forms.

Here is the code I am using for Find:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RichTextBox frm1TB = ((Form1)this.Owner).txtDisplay;

        int foundAt = frm1TB.Text.IndexOf(searchText.Text);

        if (foundAt == -1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not Found");
        }
        else
        {
            frm1TB.SelectionStart = foundAt;
            frm1TB.SelectionLength = searchText.TextLength;
            frm1TB.Focus();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find next would be something like the following:

```
if (frm1TB.Text.Length >= frm1TB.Text.SelectionStart + frm1TB.Text.SelectionLength)
{
    int foundAt = frm1TB.Text.IndexOf(
        searchText.Text,
        frm1TB.Text.SelectionStart + frm1TB.Text.SelectionLength);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember index at which you found your previous entry (or even better, at which you should start *find next* search) and then simply use [`IndexOf(string, int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33.aspx) overload, which allows you to start search at specified position. First, simply add *next search start index* field to your class:

```
private int nextSearchStartIndex;
```

Now, your `Find` method needs to keep update this index appropriately:

```
if (foundAt == -1)
{
    this.nextSearchStartIndex = 0;
    MessageBox.Show("Not Found");
}
else
{
    this.nextSearchStartIndex = foundAt + searchText.TextLength;
    // ...
}
```

And `FindNext` becomes trivial:

```
// ...
var foundAt = frm1TB.Text.IndexOf(searchText.Text, 
    this.nextSearchStartIndex);
// Here you can use exactly same update index logic as in Find
```

Comment: I implemented this on my code, and it works! Need some tweaking here and there, but I managed to blog it up! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the IndexOf() method for it, you have to switch to Regular Expressions.

Here is an example how you can easily get all the search entries in RichtBox.Text:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Regex re = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(searchText.Text.ToString(),RegexOptions.None);
MatchCollection mc = re.Matches(frm1TB.Text.ToString());
foreach (var ma in mc)
{

//do what you want
}
```